# I need a good mysql query to receive information from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function:

```
function view_user_anunt($user) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM `anunturi`
            FULL OUTER JOIN tranzactie
            ON anunturi.tranzactie = tranzactie.id_tranzactie WHERE `anunturi.user`=:code";

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':code', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) 
        {
            $view[]="
            <tr>
            <td>".$result['id_anunt']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_tranzactie']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_proprietate']."</td>
            <td><a href='#' id='vizualizare'>Select</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' id='modificare'>Select</a></td>
            </tr>";

        }
    return $view;


}
```

and 3 tables:

**anunturi**

- id_anunt (int) auto increment
- tranzactie(int)
- tip (int)
- user(int)

**tranzactie**

- id_tranzactie (int) auto increment
- den_tranzactie varchar

**tip**

- id_proprietate (int) auto increment
- den_proprietate varchar

I need a good query or an ideea to get transaction name (den_tranzactie) and proprietate name den_proprietate for each row from anunturi where anunturi.user = $user.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In case you wondered: `anunturi` stands for ads in Romanian. @OP: Please post your questions in internationally understandable format.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk - I don't see the issue to be honest. The question itself is perfectly readable in English. The fact there's some odd names used in the schema doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql query

```
 $query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
         FROM table1 t1 
         LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.foreightkey_id
         LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.foreightkey_id
         WHERE t1.user=:code
";
```

You can use INNER JOIN to receive only the rows witch have data in all tables. for example

```
$query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
             FROM table1 t1 
             INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.foreightkey_id
             INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.foreightkey_id
             WHERE t1.user=:code
    ";
```

or if you want get all data from table1 and table2 which are connected and from table 3 only that which are connected

```
$query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
                 FROM table1 t1 
                 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.foreightkey_id
                 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.foreightkey_id
                 WHERE t1.user=:code
        ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
'
SELECT t.den_tranzactie, tip.den_proprietate 
FROM
anunturi a
JOIN tranzactie t ON a.tranzactie = t.id_tranzactie 
JOIN tip ON a.tip = tip.id_proprietate 
WHERE a.user =:code
```

Comment: You've got a stray square bracket in your second JOIN

Comment: don't string `$user` into a query that, as the OP shows, is going to be passed to `prepare` -> it's a prepared stmt, not a query literal

Comment: @AsdasdasdAsdasdasd - Might have been some typos. I fixed some. What error are you getting?